# how do I make ckeditor to display bootstrap icon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I have insterted an anchor tag like the following line in CKEDITOR textarea running in Ruby on Rails with bootstrap imported in my application.js and mystyle.css:

```
<a href="#" toggle="tooltip" title="Here!"> <i class="icon-pencil"> </i> </a>
```

but the CKEDITOR textarea won't show the bootstrap pencil icon, however, if I check the source, the anchor tags are there. And if I render the file, it shows the pencil icon correctly. But just not showing in the ckeditor textarea! (simply is Not WYSIWYG.) What am I missing? do I need to import bootstrap in ckeditor css and/or config.js? how? and whatelse? Please help. Thanks a lot.

Here is the generated html code:

```
<p>This is a test<a href="#" title="Here!" toggle="tooltip"> <i class="icon-pencil"> </i> </a></p>
```

Thanks.

Thanks for the hint, Nenotlep. What you mentioned is exactly what I suspected. But I am still struggling on where and how to add the bootstrap in contents.css: this is what I have in my Gem file where I include my bootstrap:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.1.0'
```

in my app/assets/javascripts/application.js, I have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.min
//= require bootstrap-tooltip
//= require bootstrap-popover
//= require bootstrap
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require_tree .
```

and in app/assets/stylesheets/mystyle.css.scss, I have:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

I checked my app/assets directory, I cannot find ckeditor subdirectory anywhere. So I tried to create a dir called app/assets/stylesheets/ckeditor and under it I add a file called contents.css and add a line in the file as below:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

then try again, the result is still the same: the bootstrap pencil icon still missing in ckeditor textarea. The error message I got from rails server running locally is:

```
Started GET "/assets/ckeditor/bootstrap" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-22 17:35:23 -0700
Served asset /ckeditor/bootstrap - 404 Not Found (7ms)
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/ckeditor/bootstrap"):
```

I knew that bootstrap is out of reach by ckeditor, but just don't know how to configure ckeditor to include bootstrap....., any help are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Paul, please paste the generated code so we can have a better idea of what is happening with that class when the editor is created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 'bundle show' to find out where the installed ckeditor directory located (if you use Gemfile to install ckeditor):

```
bundle show ckeditor
```

for example, in my machine it returns the following directory:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ckeditor-4.0.2
```

cd to the above directory and open vendor/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/contents.css file and add one line on the top of the file to integrate bootstrap into ckeditor as below:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

that's it. You may need to restart your server (rails s) to show the effect.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the CSS that defines the icon to show is not active in the CKEditor. There is a class in your installation directory called `contents.css` that contains the CSS definitions for things inside CKEditor. Insert your icon CSS, which apparently is in mystyle.css, there.

CKEditor does not inherit classes from it's parent page because it runs in a frame.

Comment: thanks for the help. Refer to the next answer for the steps to locate the contents.css and what to add.